# Page Loading Widget jquerymobile 1.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm not able to get this PageLoading-Widget from jquerymobile working. I'm trying to call this every time a page is changed. 
This is my code:

Call methods for blocking and unblocking on every page change:

```
var tmpChangePage = $.mobile.changePage;
var globalChangePageTimeout = false;
$.mobile.changePage = function(toPage, options) {
    blockUI();
    if (globalChangePageTimeout)
        clearTimeout(globalChangePageTimeout);

    globalChangePageTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        tmpChangePage(toPage, options);
        unblockUI();
    }, 100);
};
```

blockUi():

```
function blockUI() {
$.mobile.loading('show', {
    text: 'loading',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'a'
});
}
```

I think it should work, i'm not doing anything else as they do in their example here: http://stage.api.jquerymobile.com/page-loading/

Anyone has an idea what is missing?

Comment: Give us more information about your problem. jQM ajax loader is a buggy thing. Is ajax loader showing briefly or not at all? Also what desktop and mobile browser are you using to test this?

Comment: It's not showing at all. I am using win7 with google chrome. I think it's hard to reproduce the problem for you all...

Comment: Tell me one more thing is changePage working correctly?

Comment: Yes. It also calls the blockUi() and unblockUi() correctly.

Comment: I need to take a look at jQM 1.3 first but here's an advice. Create a small basic test example (2 pages), test it with jQM 1.2 and 1.3, also use chrome and firefox. jQM 1.2 had a problem with ajax loader and chrome, for some reason ajax loader would show one moment and disappear instantly. Also version 1.3 is still not fully stable.